# Force NFSv3 on WIN2K16?

Tags: configuration, nfs, windows-server-2016

I have a multi-purpose Windows server 2016 used for automations.

I also use it to provide NFS sharing, but recently I discovered a legacy system I need only supports NFSv3, and won't mount NFSv4.1 provided by the server.

Is there any way I can configure a share to use a lower version of NFS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enable older versions of NFS protocol support using PowerShell

```
Set-NfsServerConfiguration -EnableNfsv2 $False -EnableNfsv4 $True -EnableNfsv3 $True
```

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/nfs/set-nfsserverconfiguration?view=win10-ps#examples

Comment: Wait, it actually didn't work - although using powershell and gui options seemed promising, that didn't really turn on NFSv3, and even turning off NFSv4.1 via powershell or gui didn't really turned them off (although the gui shows it is). Any idea?

Comment: The page mentions "For some changes to take effect, you must restart Services for NFS. The cmdlet prompts you to restart if necessary." I'll assume you tried that and a reboot already. Does Get-NfsServerConfiguration show ```EnableNFSV3 : Enabled```? Curious how you're testing if it really turns on or not

Comment: I rebooted the whole server and it worked. It seems like restarting the service was not enough, and from some reason my WDS also depends on it (although you don't need server for nfs to run a WDS). It was blocking the changes, but now it works. Thank you.

Comment: Great to hear it worked!